# Is it possible to check if multiple string indexes match a variable?

Tags: python

I have a tic tac toe game I made for a milestone project, and currently I have a long if/elif statement that checks all 8 possible win states. I'm trying to simplify it.

```
board = ['PLACEHOLDER', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
tag = X

# Vertical win check
if board[7] == tag and board[4] == tag and board[1] == tag:
    endgame()
elif board[8] == tag and board[5] == tag and board[2] == tag:
    endgame()
elif board[9] == tag and board[6] == tag and board[3] == tag:
    endgame()
# Horizontal win check
elif board[7] == tag and board[8] == tag and board[9] == tag:
    endgame()
elif board[4] == tag and board[5] == tag and board[6] == tag:
    endgame()
elif board[1] == tag and board[2] == tag and board[3] == tag:
    endgame()
# Diagonal win check
elif board[7] == tag and board[5] == tag and board[3] == tag:
    endgame()
elif board[1] == tag and board[5] == tag and board[9] == tag:
    endgame()
```

Is it possible to check multiples indexes in `board` at once against the `tag` string? Something like these two, which I already know don't work:

```
if board[7, 4, 1] == tag:
    endgame()

if board[7], [4], [1] == tag:
    endgame()
```

Or is it even worth trying to simplify?

Comment: Why isn't it a 3x3 matrix, like the TicTacToe game is? That makes it possible to check 3 verticals in a loop, 3 horizontals in a loop and 2 diagonals in a loop. - 3 loops versus 8 if/else

Comment: If you convert your board array to a numpy array, you can do something like `(board[[1,2]] == "-").all()`

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have a display() function that prints the board in a grid, I just didn't think I should include the entire script since my issue was specifically about checking win states. I haven't learned matrices yet, but this sounds great, and I'll definitely come back and try it out for practice once I learn about them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def endgame():
    print('game end!')


board = ['PLACEHOLDER', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
tag = 'X'
idx = [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [7, 5, 3], [1, 5, 9]]

for cond in idx:
    if board[cond[0]] == tag and board[cond[1]] == tag and board[cond[2]] == tag:
        endgame()
```

You could do something like this, which keeps all the win conditions in a list, and iterates over each one, checking if it's true and ending the game if it's true.

As khelwood points out, a more clean version of this takes advantage of variable unpacking/destructuring.

```py
for i, j, k in idx:
    if i == tag and j == tag and k == tag:
        endgame()
```

As Olvin points out, generalizing to dynamic board sizes, with the all() function, we can write this as

```py
for cond in idx:
    if all(board[i] == tag for i in cond):
        endgame()
```

Comment: Easier with `for i,j,k in idx:`

Comment: `if all(board[i] == tag for i in cond)` looks more universal.

Comment: Ooh I like this! I take it this means it isn't possible to check multiple indexes against a string in a single statement?

Comment: @arcadian As far as I know, the easiest and pretty close way to do that would be with the all() function liked Olvin described above. But if you're asking about a ```board[a, b, c] == string```  statement, as far as I know, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

A definition like

```
idx = [[8, 5, 2], [7, 4, 1], [7, 6, 3], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 5, 9], [7, 5, 3]]
```

is a lot of magic numbers. Please make an experiment and try how long it takes you to figure out where the bug in above code is.

IMHO you'd be better off designing a 2D field. The following code has no magic numbers except 3, which is easily explained.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def endgame(player: str):
    print(f"{player} won")
    pass


board = [["x", "x", "o"], ["o", "x", "o"], ["o", "-", "o"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(board)
print(df)
for player in ["x", "o"]:
    won = any((df == player).sum(axis=0) == 3)  # verticals
    won |= any((df == player).sum(axis=1) == 3)  # horizontals
    won |= (np.diag(df) == player).sum() == 3  # diagonal
    won |= (np.diag(np.fliplr(df)) == player).sum() == 3  # opposite diagonal
    if won:
        endgame(player)
```